# Android Global Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding

Can anybody give me a suggestion for android data binding.
I want my android application view components tied to a global data model.
This data model might be setted in Application object in application loading phase. 
And later, once this data modal be modified, can appear in application immediately.

Comment: ContentProvider(data model) + Loaders ... Loaders will requery CP for you if you do ContentResolver.notifyChange in update/insert/delete of CP and add cursor.setNotificationUri before you return it in CP query

Comment: Perhaps I should customize Loader to get data from Application, because I wanna let Application class handle my data model.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you the new Data Binding framework that Google released during last I/O. [Here](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) you have a tutorial with its features. I'm trying it and it is very powerful.

Comment: I agree with @icastell, the new Android Databinding is a good to go when looking for databinding on Android. I'm also using it for a new activity in my App and it works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @icastell, the new Android Databinding library is best if you want to use databinding on Android. However, there are still very few good examples for the same.

I have uploaded some sample projects on Github showing various use case scenarios of data binding. You can visit them here -

1. [Data binding with RecyclerView](https://github.com/rohankandwal/Marshmallow-Databinding-w-RecyclerView)
2. [Data binding 2 way communication (data model -> object and vice versa)](https://github.com/rohankandwal/Android-Data-Binding-2-way-communication)
3. [Basic login form with validation using data binding](https://github.com/rohankandwal/LoginFormW-DataBinding)

Although these are basic examples but you can use them to get a hang on data binding.