# How to set -source 1.7 in Android Studio and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, java-7

I'm getting following error when trying to compile my project in Android Studio:

```
Gradle: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
```

I have 1.7 set as target in all project preferences I've found. Also the path displayed in project SDK's under 1.7 SDK is correct path to java 1.7 installation.

Even when I run java -version in terminal, it tells me I'm running on java 1.7.

I have tried to set JAVA_HOME env variable to this:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The error does not go away.  How do I eliminate the error?

Comment: Do you have `sourceCompatibility` set in your build.gradle?

Comment: Java 7 support was added at build tools 19. Please, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Java 7 support was added at build tools 19. You can now use features like the diamond operator, multi-catch, try-with-resources, strings in switches, etc. Add the following to your `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Gradle 1.7+, Android gradle plugin 0.6.+ are required.

Note, that only try with resources require `minSdkVersion` 19. Other features works on previous platforms.

[Link to android gradle plugin user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7)

[Link to see how source vs target are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654951/gradle-sourcecompatibility-vs-targetcompatibility)

Comment: Does this work in Android Studio only or is it possible to make this work also in Eclipse with ADT?

Comment: It is possible with latest ADT for Eclipse. Check full description here: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/eclipseadt226preview

Comment: woohoo for string switches!

Comment: Note that try-with-resources can only be used with API 19 or higher.

Answer (score 73):

Maybe these answers above are old but with the new Android Studios 1, you do the following to see the module to run on 1.7 (or 1.6 if you prefer). Click File --> Project Structure. Select the module you want to run and then under "Source Compatibility" and "Target Compatibility", select 1.7. Click "OK".

[image: Project Structure screen of Android Studios 1]

Comment: I guess this is correct answer for the latest android-studio. Wish I could make this also a correct answer..

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: It's just a convenience feature, it will insert the previously described "compileOptions" code into the gradle file.

Comment: How can I set this to 8?

Comment: I can't see 1.8 and 1.9? Even though the About -> Help says Android studio is using 1.8 JRE.

Answer (score 14):

You can change it in new Android studio version(0.8.X)

FIle-> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler (Expand it by clicking left arrow) -> Java Compiler -> You can change the Project bytecode version here

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Latest Android Studio 1.4.

Click File->Project Structure->SDK Location->JDK Location.

You could also set individual module JDK Version compatibility by going to the Module (below the SDK Location), and edit the Source Compatibility accordingly. (note, this only applies to Android Module).

Comment: This setting is confusing, because it affects all projects, even though it is named "Project Structure".

Answer (score 5):

Right click on your project > Open Module Setting > Select "Project" in "Project Setting" section

Change the Project SDK to latest(may be API 21) and Project language level to 7+

Answer (score 4):

At current, Android doesn't support Java 7, only Java 6. New features in Java 7 such as the diamond syntax are therefore not currently supported.
Finding sources to support this isn't easy, but I could find that the Dalvic engine is built upon a subset of [Apache Harmony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Harmony) which only ever supported Java up to version 6. And if you check the [system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for developing Android apps it also states that at least JDK 6 is needed (though this of course isn't real proof, just an indication). And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535385/how-does-androids-java-version-relate-to-a-java-se-version) says pretty much the same as I have. If I find anything more substancial, I'll add it.

**Edit:**
It seems Java 7 support has been added since I originally wrote this answer; check the answer by *Sergii Pechenizkyi*.

Comment: Here, a similar question with a link on how to overcome the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487682/diamond-operator-is-not-supported

Answer (score 2):

Always use latest SDK version to build:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

It does **not affect runtime behavior**,  but give you latest programming features.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your Gradle and look for **sourceCompatibility** and change it from **1.6** to **7**. That worked for me at least.

You can also go into your module settings and set the **Source/Target Compatibility** to 1.7.

[Module settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PfX2.png)

That will produce the following code in your Gradle:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```