# androidstudio set java version 1.7

Tags: java, version, android-studio

I'm trying to use java version 1.7 with android studio but unfortunately it is not working properly...
If set the version in `File->Other settings -> Default project structure` to

```
  Project SDK:
  java version 1.7.0_06

  Project language level:
  7.0 Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch
```

But when I use a switch-statement with a string I get an error which should be possible in java 1.7, so do I need to set any other settings?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No... there is no settings to change. Android SDK don't support full java 7 syntax, so you can't use it.

Note that java.nio.* (new in java 7 API) is supported by latest android version.

Answer (score 9):

You can change it in new Android studio version(0.8.X)

FIle-> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> Compiler (Expand it by clicking left arrow) -> Java Compiler -> You can change the Project bytecode version here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change `jdk` version from F`ile > Other settings > Default Project structure`. Then `JDK location`:

[image]

Comment: doesn't exist (Android Studio 2.0)