# JDK 1.7 not shown in Program Files folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have started developing an Android application in Android Studio. After starting Android Studio it gives me an error: "compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7". So I ran `java -version` at the Commmand Prompt and it shows I have 1.7. But in Program Files there is a folder for JDK 1.6 but not for 1.7. JRE of 1.7 is there, but not JDK 1.7.

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check Program Files and Program Files (x86)

Comment: I think in using java -version only shows jre version. not jdk. am I right?

Comment: In File -> Project Structure (Strg+Alt+Shift+S) under 'SDK Location' you can check if you point to the right JDK. If only your JRE is Java 1.7 download the Java 7 JDK additionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "javac -version" instead of "java -version" to confirm JDK installed version

It seems that you have a 1.7 Java Runtime but only 1.6 SDK installed.

Just get the correct SDK installer from java.com.

Answer (score -1):

new:
Idea is you can simply set you projects jdk  any version you want, different from os installed one, just make sure you download it and referenece from the android studio
Same story different interfaces, donno if  downvotes were  necesary

https://askubuntu.com/questions/467870/how-to-set-the-jdk-for-android-studio

[androidstudio set java version 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443403/androidstudio-set-java-version-1-7)

old(sry tought is eclipse):

[How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

And make sure you have jdk available for eclipse to set it incase you dotn have it. Else just change type

Comment: edited. my bad i was not paying attention, by the way downvotes should be reconsider when someone fixed his mistake ;)

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall all jres and jdks, reinstall the jdk you need (jre is included). Be carefull with the bit-versions, always install the correct one