# Gradle build failure (incompatible magic value)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

It seems like without any reason the Gradle refuses to build the project in Android Studio. I haven't change anything in the configurations and I can't find any reason of this error. The output is the following

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 931269604 in class file build_f63dreec96sk8elmstb53lfie
```

No any Android library is recognized. So maybe there might be some problems with sdk but I have checked the dependencies and the path was set correctly. Here is a screenshot of my build.gradle.

[image]

I have already tried

1) rebuilding and cleaning the project.

2) File -> invalidate caches and restart

Are there any other ideas about fixing this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably, the problem is coming from one of your dependencies. And, of those, the JARs in `libs/` would be the most likely candidate IMHO. Make sure you have the right versions of those JARs and that they are not corrupted somehow.

Comment: did you try to remove compile fileTree line?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help also.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who finds this in future.
I had this issue and resolved it by typing:

```
gradlew --recompile-scripts
```

The problem was that Gradle had a precompiled build script from a previous version of Java. The .class file for that script was invalid, hence the error. You need to recompile that script.

Comment: You could try clearing your gradle cache, I imagine you can google to find it. I'm on Windows so it's in my "C:\Users" user profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have a project or module that was compiled using a source JRE version less than a dependency.

Try the following

`sourceCompatibility = 1.6`
`targetCompatibility = 1.6`

More information is here 
[Gradle sourceCompatibility has no effect to subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028438/gradle-sourcecompatibility-has-no-effect-to-subprojects)