# How configure multiple gradle.properties files in Gradle for multiple projects?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have multiple projects and build using Gradle 2.4.

I want to overwrite the `org.gradle.java.home` parameter in each project and try to add gradle.properties file for each project and overwrite the parameter.

I have set the main gradle project `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Java/jdk1.6.0` and overwrite in subproject as `org.gradle.java.home=C:/Java/jdk1.7.0_45`

But it is not working as expected and I'm getting

**invalid source release: 1.7**

error message.

Could someone give idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you wanting to run a different version of gradle for different projects? If so, you should be making use of the Gradle Wrapper

Comment: @MrWiggles I'm trying to use different java versions not different version of gradle.

Comment: You mean you have a multi-module build and you want a different version of java for child modules? I believe you should use the highest version of the JDK you need and just set sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility for each module

Comment: @MrWiggles 
Can't I overwrite the  'org.gradle.java.home' in gradle.properties file?
My requirement is that. May I know is it possible or not?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware as the gradle process has already spun up - what is it you're trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my tests:

I have created **blank** root project without specifying which java to use and included two **subprojects** with different `org.gradle.java.home` and `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` for each subproject and it works.

**Project structure**:

```
/build.gradle <-- root project (no sourceCompatibility or targetCompatibility here .. just blank)
/settings.gradle <-- include the subprojects
/gradle.properties <-- root gradle.properties (no org.gradle.java.home here)
  /sub1/build.gradle
  /sub1/gradle.properties
  /sub2/build.gradle
  /sub2/gradle.properties
```

**Root's settings.gradle**:

```
include 'sub1'
include 'sub2'
```

**Sub1's gradle.properties**:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/java8
```

**Sub1's build.gradle**:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

**Sub2's gradle.properties**:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/java7
```

**Sub2's build.gradle**:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

So, you can try this setup.

I guess, because you are using your root project with already defined java (not just as configuration point) - this might be the problem.

Also check these ones:

[How do I tell Gradle to use specific JDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487406/gradle-how-to-tell-gradle-to-use-specific-jdk-version-for-building-an-applica)

[Gradle sourceCompatibility has no effect to subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028438/gradle-sourcecompatibility-has-no-effect-to-subprojects)