# Android Studio: Testing: Library dependencies that have been compiled using java 8 or above

Tags: android, android-studio, cucumber, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

please help.  I am having a really horrible time with setting up my testing for android studio.

I have downloaded the calculator example to practice cumcumber code testing from the cucumber github. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/android (some of these brands btw are very strangley named)

I tried to use it with Android studio.  The program runs perfect (yay!).  The test however does not.  I have a really horrible message that just haunts me every time i run it.

```
*To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1*
```

Its the target compatibility and source compatibility i am having trouble with (have not got to the rest yet)

Here's the gradle build: as you can see i have changed the compatibility to 1.7

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "boo.thefoodhunt"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        debug {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/debug/assets', 'src/androidTest/assets/']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res', 'src/androidTest/assets/features']
        }
        main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/androidTest/assets'] }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

    //TESTING
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'

    //Espresso
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'

    //Cucumber
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.4'
    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4'
}
```

The test that is failing to run:

```
 package boo.thefoodhunt;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

@CucumberOptions(features = "features")
public class CalculatorActivitySteps extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<CalculatorActivity> {

    public CalculatorActivitySteps(SomeDependency dependency) {
        super(CalculatorActivity.class);
        assertNotNull(dependency);
    }

    @Given("^I have a CalculatorActivity$")
    public void I_have_a_CalculatorActivity() {
        assertNotNull(getActivity());
    }

    @When("^I press (\\d)$")
    public void I_press_d(final int d) {
        switch (d) {
            case 0:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_0)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 1:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_1)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 2:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_2)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 3:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_3)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 4:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_4)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 5:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_5)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 6:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_6)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 7:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_7)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 8:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_8)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 9:
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_d_9)).perform(click());
                break;
        }
    }

    @When("^I press ([+–x\\/=])$")
    public void I_press_op(final char op) {
        switch (op) {
            case '+':
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_op_add)).perform(click());
                break;
            case '–':
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_op_subtract)).perform(click());
                break;
            case 'x':
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_op_multiply)).perform(click());
                break;
            case '/':
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_op_divide)).perform(click());
                break;
            case '=':
                onView(withId(R.id.btn_op_equals)).perform(click());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Then("^I should see (\\S+) on the display$")
    public void I_should_see_s_on_the_display(final String s) {
        onView(withId(R.id.txt_calc_display)).check(matches(withText(s)));
    }
}
```

Now ive tried this:

[Error when using a jar in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445220/error-when-using-a-jar-in-my-project)

and this:
[Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

and this:
[Gradle sourceCompatibility has no effect to subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028438/gradle-sourcecompatibility-has-no-effect-to-subprojects)

in both the project gradle and the app gradle.  But i'm am thinking as its only coming with testing...these will not help and its something to do with the dependencies and for that i am pretty stuck.  Can anyone help! thanks in advance

Comment: oh the jdk.... is currently jdk1.8.0_74 and im using android studio  2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for any one that is having the same problem.  I sussed it! (I think!) its lead on to other problems with the program but at least i have the test running and its communicating with the device and reading through the tests without having paddy.  The tests however are coming up with a brand new problem (for another question, another day) New problem if anyone is interested:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
```

im guessing that its something to do with not all the buttons not in view (not my design! FYI) so we adjust this tomorrow.

Now on to the solution(ish)

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/893: comment from  programmerdave on 18 Nov 2015 helped with the gradle setup.

This brought a whole new bug!

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.properties
    File1: C:\Users\kyleparker\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.crashlytics.android\crashlytics\1.1.13\e821eafa1bf489a26bdb71f95078c26785b37a1\crashlytics-1.1.13.jar
    File2: C:\Users\kyleparker\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp\okhttp\2.4.0\40340c0748190fe897baf7bffbc1b282734294e5\okhttp-2.4.0.jar
```

But managed to fix this quite quickly.  thanks to these guys
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194980

Anyway apparently two different issues that created havoc (a day and half).

Heres the gradle for the Calkulator demo (link in question) - it all feels a bit messy and if anyone has a nice cleaner solution please let me know

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cucumber.cukeulator"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testApplicationId "cucumber.cukeulator.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "cucumber.cukeulator.test.Instrumentation"
    }

    packagingOptions {

        //these are the ones that fixed it for me
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'

        //but im not going to  remove my first attempt just in case ;)
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.4') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }

    androidTestCompile('info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.4') {
        exclude module: 'cucumber-jvm-deps'
    }

    // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    // androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'

    androidTestCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.3'

}
```

So all in all it seems to be that jvm-deps......well who knew

Answer (score 1):

You have a dependency, unclear which, that is compiled for Java 8 and you have specified Java 7 in your build.

The error message `This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.` is they key here.

My approach would be to change the Java version to 8. If that didn't do the trick, reduce the problem. That is, start with a new project without dependencies, and code, and add very small parts until I found what caused to error above.

That is, apply Galls Law:

"A complex system that works is invariably found to have evolved from a simple system that worked. A complex system designed from scratch never works and cannot be patched up to make it work. You have to start over with a working simple system. – John Gall (1975, p.71)"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gall_%28author%29

Comment: Thank you for your advice (And Mr Gall!), I will look again, today.  It was such a simple test case it got to the extent I was looking at an overall rather then what you suggested.  I was messing with the dependeces (Esspresso, All Cucumber etc) and trying to 'patch' it all up, changing settings and changing the gradle build, I probably made it worse, it was just a dud frustrating process and was just expecting things to work together nicely. Thanks again