# Using Java 8 with LibGDX

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, java-8, build.gradle

I'm writing a game in Java using LibGDX, with only `desktop` as the targeted platform. I just created a new LibGDX project, and imported some existing code into it, but now I'm getting a few errors. Specifically, using the `diamond operator`. For example, this line of code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> connectionsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

is generating this error:

```
Error:(20, 37) java: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

Ideally, I'd like to use Java 8. The Gradle files in the module I imported were preserved, so I changed the `sourceCompatibility` line in all the other `build.gradle` files throughout the project from `1.6` to `1.8`, and I made sure that in the `Project Structure > Project > Language Level` was set to Java 8. However, I'm still getting this issue. What else do I need to change for my project to use Java 8?

Comment: It depends what IDE you're using, you need to compile with Java 8.

Comment: @JacobG. I'm using Intellij, I made sure the `Project Structure > Project > Language Level` was set to Java 8 and the run configuration was set to use Java 8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using IntelliJIDEA, make changes in three places.

1. `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` in build.gradle file of all modules
2. `Project Structure > Project > Language Level`
3. `Project Structure > Modules > Sources Tab on all modules > Language Level`

Comment: Ah, the Module's language level, that's what I forgot. I wonder why it didn't automatically use the project default.Thanks!

Comment: How would you add `sourceCompatibility` to the build.gradle file?
I added it to the top of the file and got and error.

Comment: @JesperHustad check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24862369/3445320