# How to change Java version of libgdx project?

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx

I'm creating simple game with libgdx java library and can't figure out how to change java version of the project.

Problem: It uses 1.7 and I am trying to change it to 1.8

Things I tried( referring to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43724074/16540902) ):

1. Changed sdk version to 1.8 in Project Structure > Project
2. Changed versions of each module in module section
3. Tried to modify build.gradle file to run with 1.8 java

   buildscript {

   ```
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.16'
            classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7'


        }
    }

    allprojects {
        apply plugin: "eclipse"



        version = '1.0'
        ext {
            appName = "Mario"
            gdxVersion = '1.11.0'
            roboVMVersion = '2.3.16'
            box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
            ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
            aiVersion = '1.8.2'
            gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            google()
            gradlePluginPortal()
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
            maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }

    project(":desktop") {
        apply plugin: "java-library"

        // Added
        apply plugin: "java"
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8


        dependencies {
            implementation project(":core")
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

        }
    }

    project(":core") {
        apply plugin: "java-library"

            // Added 
        apply plugin: "java"
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8

        dependencies {
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        }
    }

    project(":html") {
        apply plugin: "java-library"
        apply plugin: "gwt"
        apply plugin: "war"
        apply plugin: "org.gretty"

        //Added
        apply plugin: "java"
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8



        dependencies {
            implementation project(":core")
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
            api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"

        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of changing the `sourceCompatibility` to 1.8 is correct, but you did it in the wrong file. There are **several build.gradle files** in a libgdx project.

In your root directory (where you found the build.gradle file that you mentioned in your question), there is a directory `core`. Inside this project there is another build.gradle that includes the `sourceCompatibility`.
The file should look like this:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7 // change to 1.8 here to use java-8 features
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-core"
```