# Gradle / IntelliJ IDEA: sourceCompatibility reverts to previous value in IDE settings

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, java-8, java-11, source-compatibility

Setting `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to `JavaVersion.VERSION_11` has no expected effect on my IntelliJ/Grade/Java project.

Even though I set *Project SDK* and *Project Language Level* in **Project Structure** manually to 11, it reverted to 8 and 6 after I  **Refresh Gradle project** (or **Import Changes**). See below image:

[image]

---

To ensure I created a **new project** and test these in it. This is its tree view:

[image]

The only **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Gradle version is `4.10.2` as you can see it in **gradle-wrapper.properties** file:

```
#Tue Nov 13 00:53:45 IRST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

And this is environment information:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.5281.24, built on June 12, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

This is an image from my SDKs:

[image]

---

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24862369/5318303), I made below configuration to **build.gradle**, but the problem persists:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

repositories {
    ...
```

And also below configuration according to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21051506/5318303) on the same post:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

repositories {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such issues compatibility of tools matter, you can upgrade your IDE version to a version ***>= 2018.2***.

Quoting a JetBrains blog [#Java11 in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/java-11-in-intellij-idea-2018-2/)

> *The next version of Java is due out in September, and IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 is ready for it.*