# gradle compile success, but fail to run project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**PROBLEM**

After I try to find out what is root cause of problem. why I can build successfully but unable to run project. It's because one jar file call 'signalr-client-sdk.jar' if I put in libs folder and run the following error message generated. please help me to identify it. I don't know what to do now.

**FILE JAR** [DOWNLOAD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7yxih0xal6jdgu/signalr-client-sdk.jar.zip?dl=0)

**ENVIRONMENT**

1. IntelliJ Idea 14.1.5
2. Java JDK 1.7.0_79
3. gardle wrapper - gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
4. Latest Android SDK was updated

**GRADLE FILE**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testsinalr.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
Error:Gradle: 16:08:25.422 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes","position":{},"original":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","position":{},"original":"Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\t... 12 more","position":{},"original":"\t... 12 more"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"1 error; aborting","position":{},"original":"1 error; aborting"}
16:08:25.429 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:08:25.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:08:25.430 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:08:25.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:08:25.431 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
16:08:25.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
16:08:25.432 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
16:08:25.433 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
16:08:25.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
16:08:25.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
16:08:25.434 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
16:08:25.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
16:08:25.435 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
16:08:25.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
16:08:25.436 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
16:08:25.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
16:08:25.437 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
16:08:25.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
16:08:25.438 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
16:08:25.439 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
16:08:25.439 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
16:08:25.439 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
16:08:25.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
16:08:25.440 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
16:08:25.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
16:08:25.441 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
16:08:25.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
16:08:25.442 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
16:08:25.443 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
16:08:25.443 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
16:08:25.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
16:08:25.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
16:08:25.444 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
16:08:25.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
16:08:25.445 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
16:08:25.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
16:08:25.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
16:08:25.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
16:08:25.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
16:08:25.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
16:08:25.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
16:08:25.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
16:08:25.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
16:08:25.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
16:08:25.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.452 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
16:08:25.452 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.453 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
16:08:25.453 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
16:08:25.454 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
16:08:25.455 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
16:08:25.455 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
16:08:25.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
16:08:25.458 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.460 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
16:08:25.460 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
16:08:25.461 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.463 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
16:08:25.463 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
16:08:25.464 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
16:08:25.464 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
16:08:25.467 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
16:08:25.470 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
16:08:25.474 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:116)
16:08:25.474 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor$waitForTasksWithQuickFail$0.call(Unknown Source)
16:08:25.477 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex.taskAction(PreDex.groovy:106)
16:08:25.478 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
16:08:25.480 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
16:08:25.481 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
16:08:25.483 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
16:08:25.483 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
16:08:25.486 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
16:08:25.488 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
16:08:25.489 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 55 more
16:08:25.491 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
16:08:25.492 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
16:08:25.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1295)
16:08:25.493 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:122)
16:08:25.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1247)
16:08:25.495 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$preDexLibrary$1.call(Unknown Source)
16:08:25.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy:150)
16:08:25.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PreDex$PreDexTask.call(PreDex.groovy)
16:08:25.496 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
16:08:25.500 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
16:08:25.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
16:08:25.503 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 6 more
16:08:25.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
Error:Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/Users/X-tivity/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2.1-all/c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53/gradle-2.2.1'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your real error is

```
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
```

This happens because your `signalr-client-sdk.jar` was compiled with Java 1.8:

```
javap -verbose -classpath signalr-client-sdk.jar microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.transport.HttpClientTransport | grep version

  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
```

`52` is Java 1.8.

You should rebuild SignalR client with Java 1.7 (`javap` should return `major version: 51`).

Comment: remove `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` from `compileOptions` or set it to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` not working

Comment: @JongzPuangput I updated my answer. It should solve your issue now.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh My Goshhhh Thank you so much... you save my world @mixel

Comment: Thank you mixel & @JongzPuangput !

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of gradle

Or you can use

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
```

Then **Rebuild and  File --> Invalidate caches/restart**

For more information you can read this SO Answer

> [Error: Gradle: execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847482/error-gradle-execution-failed-for-task-apppredexdebug)

**Edited**

Upgrade version

```
 sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435069/android-switch-to-gradle-doesnt-compile-jre7-code-features

Comment: do what you suggest, but no hope

Comment: @JongzPuangput Upgrade your `JavaVersion`