# JDK 1.7 String switch statement is not working

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, java-7

### [Fixed]

Thanks to @Visil below (accepted answer). I added the recommended code to `build.gradle` and waited after syncing gradle. The following popped up shortly after that...

[image]

---

### Original Question

I am doing some Android programming with Android Studio 0.5.9, and I wanted to have some `String` switch statements. I set up everything, but the compiler is complaining that it cannot handle them.

String Switch-statements were introduced in JDK 1.7 so I am confused as to why I cannot do this.

Just to prove I am using JDK 1.7, you can check the image below...
[image]

...also, my machine has JDK 1.8 installed...
[image]

...what's up with this?

---

### [UPDATE]

### File >> Other Settings >> Default Settings

[image]

### File >> Other Settings >> Default Project Structure

[image]

### Build.gradle

[image]

Comment: you must set the language level in Intellij. The level is standard 1.6. You find this in the projekt settings

Comment: can you go more in-depth? I am not seeing this right now

Comment: I use only Intellij, but Android studio is based on Intellij. Steps in Intellij: 1. File -> Project Structure 2. Projekt 3. Projekt Language Level.

Comment: I added to screenshots of some other settings I seen with the JDK. Everything is set to Java (JDK) 1.7

Comment: Got nothing? Upvote so we can get this figured out

Comment: I found nothing. One tip, use Intellij. In intellij is everthing what is in android studio (http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/ http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56837/discussion-between-christopher-rucinski-and-schlagi123).

Comment: How does your build.gradle look like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your gradle source compatibilty configuration:

> With Android KitKat (buildToolsVersion 19) you can use the diamond
>   operator, multi-catch, strings in switches, try with resources, etc.
>   To do this, add the following to your build file:
>
> ```
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 19
>     buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
>
>     defaultConfig {
>         minSdkVersion 7
>         targetSdkVersion 19
>     }
>
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that you can use minSdkVersion with a value earlier than 19, for
>   all language features except try with resources. If you want to use
>   try with resources, you will need to also use a minSdkVersion of 19.
>
> You also need to make sure that Gradle is using version 1.7 or later
>   of the JDK. (And version 0.6.1 or later of the Android Gradle plugin.)

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Using-sourceCompatibility-1.7

Comment: I added my Build.gradle code as an image. Please check it.

Comment: Also, I did add the ComplileOptions and saved. The problem is still there. I might completely restart Android Studio just to make sure it takes effect