# Error:(24, 46) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Tags: java, android, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting error in my `ArrayAdapter<>`

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,name1));
```

> Error:(24, 46) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
>   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Then I updated my java version to

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
```

But still I'm getting the same error.
OS I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You have to update the language level of your ide, not only your jdk.

Comment: What IDE are you using, Eclipse?

Comment: no.Android Studio (Beta)0.8.2

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle

Comment: @PsHegger How to update language level of my ide?

Comment: Project Structure -> Project -> Project language level, but are you sure you can use Java 1.7 on Android?

Answer (score 5):

Now with Android Studio(I use v1.1), You can change your language level easily by clicking `File`->`Project Structure`, and in the open window follow the settings:

[image]