# Incompatible magic value with Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm working with Android Studio 1.2.2 and when I want to sync my project, it shows:

> "Error:Incompatible magic value 2586042913 in class file asLocalRepo1_9h0wx5r1a0kgvu546dwv1hdh8"

Each time I try to sync again the number of the repo increases `(asLocalRepo2_1dhgml..., asLocalRepo3_gfd5..., ...)`

I know that when a magic value is incompatible it means the file is corrupted, but I don't know which file.

Comment: `�#�!`  or `%�)` does that appear anywhere in your files? that is what I get when i try to conver the number to text. the first one is the hexadecimal value. the second the integer value? Do you pull dynamic content/libaries from the internet? if so you might have a http error. Are all your libaries in the right directories? Do their md5 checksums still match?

Comment: No, nothing like that appear in my files.
I have some libraries from the internet but they all work until then, plus I create a new project with no libraries at all and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Did you create it with a new project too? or did you place the same files in it? if so, try removing directory by directory of your files untill the problem stops appearing to narrow it down. You might have a hardware issue possibly, that you have defective ram If you run memtest86+ is your memory still ok? Just trying to think of all options. one its a corrupted file. other extreme, your pc is broken.

Comment: I created a totally new project, completely empty, but the error was still there.
I ran a memtest86+ and it shows no error, I'll think I gonna redump my PC

Comment: It might be a cpu fault too, or an error in your harddrive. have you tried reseating the cables? But if it also shows in a new project, then I have strong suspicions of a hardware failure :S but I see hardware faillures everywhere being a pc tech heh.

Comment: @Tschallacka Im also getting those encrypted-like symbols. Good thing the project is up on git and can just be pulled. Have you find fix for this ?

Comment: @ralphspoon I'd suggest you run memtest86+ from a bootable stick or a linux installation dvd, and seagate seatools long generic test on your harddrive. If you have ssd, your manufacturers test software.

Comment: still wondering what made the errors. did you fix yours ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and this fixed it right away

answer form this question: 
[How to set -source 1.7 in Android Studio and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle)

I added this to build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

So now i have this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Comment: when trying to sync the gradle file an error shows. 'Project name' project refresh failed