# Why does Android Studio keep toggling `languageLevel`?

Tags: android, android-studio

Very often, when I look at the `git diff` output for my Android app built with Android Studio, I see the following. Sometimes it is changing `languageLevel` from `JDK_1_7` to `JDK_1_8`. Other times it is changing `languageLevel` from `JDK_1_8` to `JDK_1_7`. Why so much indecision??

```
--- a/.idea/misc.xml
+++ b/.idea/misc.xml
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@
       </value>
     </option>
   </component>
-  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_7" default="true" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
+  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" default="true" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android .idea/misc.xml's languageLevel tag keeps changing JDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878888/android-idea-misc-xmls-languagelevel-tag-keeps-changing-jdks)

Answer (score 4):

1) Add this to your app `build.gradle` (inside the `android` element)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

2) Exclude the `.idea` folder from Git adding this to your project level `.gitignore`

```
# Ignore idea folder
.idea/
```

then you need to refresh your versioned files following something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757964/2910520)

> Versioning the `.idea` folder it's useful only to share some AS
>   settings with your team, if you are working alone or if you don't have
>   shared coding policies you can remove it.

Comment: Adding `compileOptions` does not prevent `misc.xml` from toggling `languageLevel`. Excluding `.idea` folder only hides the issue by making version control ignores `misc.xml` and also prevent sharing AS settings with your team (as you have already mentioned). 

This answer neither explain *why* `misc.xml` keep toggling, nor provides a solution to prevent `misc.xml` from toggling.

Comment: I think it was an AS or Intellij bug at the time, now in AS 3.4 it is not happening to me (and I am using the default gitignore where misc.xml is versioned). What i mentioned was the workaround which pretty everybody used