# How can I set Android Studio's project-jdk-name in .idea/misc.xml?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Similarly to [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878888/android-idea-misc-xmls-languagelevel-tag-keeps-changing-jdks), after upgrading a project to Android Studio 3.5, the `.idea/misc.xml` file keeps flip flopping between two developers, one on mac, another on linux with the following line:

```
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project version="4">
-  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
+  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="JDK" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
     <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes" />
   </component>
   <component name="ProjectType">
```

Essentially, the `project-jdk-name` attribute keeps switching between the values `JDK` or `1.8`. I've looked through many configuration options but can't seem to find the place where I can set this value to avoid it changing between commits on both platforms. Or maybe there is a way to ignore this specific line change while allowing changes to the rest of the file?

Comment: We (me and a collage) have the exact same issue, but we are booth on mac.
I'll keep you updated if we solve it.

Comment: @JoelBroström And, found anything?

Comment: No, nut I think it solved itself after we both updated AS to 3.6.

Comment: Have the same issue with Android Studio 3.6.3. The operating systems are Mac and Windows.

Comment: @JoelBroström I had the same issue and resolved it by updating my JAVA_HOME, check out the detailed answere here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/63413183/2064964