# Android Studio keeps changing "project-jdk-name" in misc.xml

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

We are using Android Studio (currently 3.6) on two machines (macOS).

The `.idea/misc.xml` file keeps changing the value for `project-jdk-name` from "1.8" to "1.8 (2)" back and forth.

[image: .idea/misc.xml change]

This has been going on for a while (at least since 3.4/3.5). It's happening for all projects.
Both installations are configured to use the embedded JDK (Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK location).

- How can this be stopped?
- Where does this name even come from?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by following these steps:

- opening "File > Project Structure > SDK Location"
- manually selecting a JDK location from "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/..." (must have another JDK 1.8 installed)
- clicking "Apply"
- changing the JDK location back to "Embedded SDK" from the drop menu

After doing this the value for `project-jdk-name` in `.idea/misc.xml` remains at "1.8".

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue (JDK instead of 1.8 (2)). Check your project's Project Structure's Java SDK. I had 2 options -- `Embedded` and `JAVA_HOME`, but they were pointing the same path (Android Studio's embedded one). I had Java 1.8 installed properly but did not have `JAVA_HOME` set. After I did that AS showed me the `JAVA_HOME` properly (you might need to restart AS) and after selecting it everything compiled/worked properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my case it was not even necessary to add the JAVA_HOME environment variable. Just manually selecting the JDK from "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines" and then changing back to the Embedded SDK solved the issue.