# Error running project in UdemyStudio - mentions wrong JVMs

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I just built with Gradle, things worked fine. Then I chose "run" and this error happened:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Would anyone know how to fix this one? I've never seen it before. It references Java7, but I am using Java6. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

At First set this in your **build.gradle** section .

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7 
}
```

Then Check **[ClassesWithDexForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top)** Answer .

Comment: @Genadinik You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle