# How to set Java version for non-Android module in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

In Android Studio, under `File, Project Structure` I can set the path to the JDK and with this the Java version. The command seems misplaced here as `Project Structure` suggests the structure of the current project, though this is a general setting for all projects.

Then, in the same dialog, I can go to modules and set a different Java version under source/target compatibility there, but as [How to set -source 1.7 in Android Studio and Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle) states, this setting only changes the `android` section in `gradle`, so it seems to be available only for Android projects.

- Where can I set the Java version on a per project/per module basis for non-Android modules.

Can anybody explain which setting changes what, or where this is documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom java versions for each module via the **gradle.properties** file. You can find more about it here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

You might want to use

```
org.gradle.java.home=PATH_TO_YOUR_JAVA_HOME
```