# Can I use MVVMCross outside Xamarin?

Tags: android, mobile, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

can I use `MVVMCross` library as `MVVM` platform outside `Xamarin` With any Android Native project?

if no , is there any native `MVVM` framework for android applications ?

Comment: You will hardly find anything like MVVM in java. java people are convinced it's 1990. Why do you want to use an inferior technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently MvvmCross relies on C#  - so using it on Android requires Xamarin.Android.

You could possibly port it to Java, or could try the dot42.com platform which compiles C# to Dalvik.

For pure Java alternatives, you could also try a couple of library answers from [Android data-binding (similar to WPF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007941/android-data-binding-similar-to-wpf)

Comment: dot42 might be an option for you - it's currently in a transition from byte code generation to source code generation using Roslyn - looks promising and I'm sure they'd welcome additional assistance/contributions.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would like to recommend [RoboBinding](http://robobinding.org) to you, A data-binding Presentation Model(MVVM) framework for the Android platform. There are a minimal sample app [AndroidMVVM](https://github.com/RoboBinding/AndroidMVVM) and an [album sample](https://github.com/RoboBinding/RoboBinding-album-sample), which is an android translation of Martin Fowler's original sample created to explain the Presenation Model(called MVVM in microsoft community) pattern. Both samples can be imported into Android Studio with no extra config. The pattern is an involvement from old MVC pattern and its major motivation is to further decouple UI state and logic to a PURE POJO presenation model, which allows to be easily unit tested. If you like RoboBinding, i encourage you to have a look into its source code and have a feel of its code quality.